# Is there a symmetric polygon for which the centers of connected points (that are equidistant to their neighbours on its boundary) do not overlap?

Tags: geometry, symmetry, polygons

I am looking for (a class of) symmetric polygon(s) that can have any number (odd and even) of points on its boundary, equidistant to their neighboring points, and when all pairs of points are connected by a straight line, the centers of those lines do not overlap.

For example, when the corners of a regular pentagon are connected, the centers of the four lines do not overlap, and the condition holds. However, when the corners of a square are connected, the centers of both lines overlap, and thus the condition does not hold.

I have no background in geometry, please help clarify the question if needed!

Comment: What is meant by symmetric? [all angles same, or whatever]

Comment: Symmetric might not be completely accurate, let me clarify. In a first approach I used circles rather than polygons, with points on its boundary equidistant to their neighboring points. But with an even number of points the centers of the lines overlap. I am looking for a similar shape, where the centers of the lines do not overlap, even with an even number of points.

Comment: So you are willing to give up equally spaced, if you can get even number of points placed on a circle?

Comment: Would $n$ points in  circle centered at origin, but arranged all in first quadrant (equally spaced there) be a sufficently general set to do what you want? Such a point set satisfies your requirement of no two midpoint crossings.